# Hibernate: Mapping Multi-Rows with ElementCollection - Single table no Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Looking for a solution to map multiple `student_id` rows under the same `class_id`, here is the table which has 3 fields:

```
integer id PRIMARY KEY
integer class_id;
integer student_id;
```

The table can have multiple rows under the same `class_id` like this:

```
Table = 'class'
id  class_id  student_id 
1,    1,          1
2,    1,          2
3,    1,          3
4,    2,          1
5,    3,          1
```

I'm trying to Map this into a Pojo so I can use it as follow:

```
List<UniClass> uniClasses = session.createQuery("FROM ClassOfStudent", ClassOfStudent.class).getResultList();
```

I'm trying to solve this problem by using `@ElementCollection`

Here is my attempt:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class")
public class ClassOfStudents{
   @Id
   @Column("id")
   private long m_id;

   @Column(name = "class_id")
   private long m_classId;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "class", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="class_id"))
   @Column(name = "student_id")
   private List<Long> m_studentIds;

   ....
}
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: *this table describes Many-to-Many relations*: between what and what? *I can't use @OneToMany since it's a single entity*: A one-to-many between what and what? *I'm trying to experiment with @ElementCollection*: a collection of what? Stored where?

Comment: collection of 'std_ids' stored at that table I described.

Comment: Each row of that table has one and only one std_id, stored in the column std_id of that same table. So there is no association at all, even less a collection. All you need is a column of type long.

Comment: there are multiple rows with uni_id=1 and std_id = 1,2,3 - please look at the example.

Comment: So what? There are several persons with the name "John". That doesn't mean that a person, identified by a unique person_id, has several names. A person has just one name. Just like a uni_class identified by an id has just one std_id.

Comment: is it possible to group all the std_ids that under the same uni_id when defining a Pojo ?

Comment: What identifies a UniClass (and I have no idean of what a UniClass can possibly be) is the `id` column. An instance of UniClass represents one row of the uni_class table. If you described what this tables and its columns actually represent, maybe we could advise how to best represent that, both in terms ofdatabase relations and in terms of JPA entities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190523/discussion-between-shvalb-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: the fields in the table are just ids ...they don't have a lot of meaning.
my point is that I would like somehow to have a pojo that aggregates few rows in the table which all have the same 'uni_id' value.

Answer (score 0):

The trick that made this possible is that eventually I mapped the `@Id` of the class to be `m_classId` although it's not really the primary key of the table in the DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class")
public class ClassOfStudents implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "class_id")
  private long classId;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Long.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(name = "class", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id"))
  @Column(name = "student_id", nullable = false)  
  private List<Long> m_studentIds;
...
}
```